# Expression not evaluating due to no value

Tags: python, html, templates, jinja2, variable-assignment

So I have been tossed into a Jinja2 email template scenario which I cannot figure out and hopefully can describe properly (maybe it isnt possible), but I also dont have enough knowledge about how Jinja2 and email templates work with SQL where SQL is assigning @@ values when rendering. I have the following:

```
<!-- {% set partner_shortname = '@@SHORTNAME' %} -->
<!-- {% set partner_name = '@@PARTNER' %} -->


<!--display values to check-->
<p>PARTNER NAME:  {{ partner_name }}</p>
<p>PARTNER SHORTNAME 1:  {{ partner_shortname }}</p>


<!--
{% if partner_shortname == 'ABCD' %}
     {% set hexColor = '#CC0000' %}
-->
    <p>LENGTH1: {{ partner_shortname|length }}</p>                                      
<!-- {% else %}
    {% set hexColor = '#57a377' %}
-->
   <p>LENGTH2: {{ partner_shortname|length }}</p>                                       
<!-- {% endif %}  -->

<!-- display hex code based on partner -->
<p>HEX CODE:  {{ hexColor }}</p>
```

So, my issue is as follows:  printing anything like {{ partner_shortname }} or {{ partner_name }} gives me the value that was set in the variable (ie: ABCD or Alpha Beta Charlie Delta), but when it hits my if statement partner_shortname is @@SHORTNAME and there doesnt appear to be a value of ABCD as when printed thus a length of 11 (@@SHORTNAME).  Why do the printed variables have values but the if statement does not? What am I missing?

Comment: How can you simplify this problem? Can you get this to a single variable assignment, and a single print statement? I'm not really sure what is going on here, and I think breaking this down a bit more MIGHT help.

Comment: @BrianStinar this is as simple as it gets.

     {% if partner_shortname == 'ABCD' %}
          {% set hexColor = '#CC0000' %}

Why would partner_shortname still contain @@SHORTNAME

Comment: @BrianStinar and to clarify...Autoescaping is the concept of automatically escaping special characters for you. Special characters in the sense of HTML (or XML, and thus XHTML) are &, >, <, " as well as '. from 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#controlling-autoescaping